# Odd array behaviour with strtok and fgets

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I'm working on a program that acts as a shell interpreter that reads commands with arguments and creates a child that executes the command with `execvp()`. I'm stuck on doing some string manipulation to collect a char array `*args[]`, particularly with using `fgets` and `strtok`.

Here's an MCVE of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(void){
    //initialize variables
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
    char input[MAX_LINE];
    //char input[MAX_LINE] = "some sentence unknown"; // <-- this line works fine..

    int counter = 0;
    printf("COMMANDER>");
    fflush(stdout);

    //receive input
    fgets(input,MAX_LINE,stdin);

    //parse input
    char *parser;
    parser = strtok(input," \r\t");

    //parse line
    while(parser != NULL){
                args[counter] = parser;
        counter++;  
        parser = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    //print results
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < counter + 1;i++){
        printf("1");
        printf(" - %d: %s\n",i,args[i]);    
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is the ouput. When I try to run this, I get the following output:

```
COMMANDER>some sentence unknown
1 - 0: some
1 - 1: sentence
1 - 2: unknown

1 - 3: (null)
```

My issue is that empty space. I can't tell where it's coming from and no matter what I do it appears.

From what I can tell it may be a \n character at the end of the string, or something else, but passing this into `execvp` as `execvp(args[0],args)` creates an error, as it interprets this blank line as an argument of " ".

There is a line I've commented out that's just a string assignment at the start of `main`. If this assignment is used instead of `fgets` the program works and I get the desired input:

```
COMMANDER>some sentence unknown
1 - 0: some
1 - 1: sentence
1 - 2: unknown
1 - 3: (null)
```

Thanks for reading. I'm a bit rusty on my C, so I kept at this on my own for a few hours and still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: I suggest changing the separator string to `" \n\r\t"` escpecially in the second `strtok` you omitted to separate on *any* control characters.

Comment: Just did that, fixed the issue beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `fgets` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) you will see that it says

> Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str ***will contain that newline character***.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

What you're seeing as "that empty space" is the newline that `fgets` added at the end of the string.

---

There is however a much *worse* problem in your code.

With

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
```

you define an array of pointers, but you leave this array *uninitialized*. In C uninitialized local (and non-static) variables really *are* uninitialized. Their contents will be *indeterminate* and seem almost random.

More specifically, that you happen to get a null pointer at `args[counter]` is just pure luck.

Attempting to use this pointer in any way without initialization will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution is to explicit initialize the array to be full of null pointers:

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1] = { NULL };
```

The above will "zero-initialize" all elements, which for pointers mean they will be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks! that makes a lot of sense. The null pointer at the end was originally assigned as a statement but I deleted it just before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

The line read by `fgets()` contains a trailing newline character `'\n'`. You must include it in the list of characters recognized by `strtok()` as delimiters.  Furthermore, you must pass the same list to both calls.

You also forget to set the entry at offset `count` to `NULL`. Local objects with automatic storage are uninitialized. Note also that you should not pass a null pointer to `printf` for the `%s` conversion specifier: it has undefined behavior although some implementations test the argument and output a specific string.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(void){
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];
    char input[MAX_LINE];
    int counter;

    printf("COMMANDER>");
    fflush(stdout);

    //receive input
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        //parse input
        char *parser;
        parser = strtok(input, " \f\n\r\t");

        //parse line
        count = 0;
        while (parser != NULL) {
            args[counter] = parser;
            counter++;  
            parser = strtok(NULL, " \f\n\r\t");
        }
        args[counter] = NULL;

        //print results
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
            printf("1 - %d: %s\n", i, args[i] ? args[i] : "(null)");
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```